# Height does not change on resize() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 4 div container with different height. I want that all of them have the same height whenever I load the page or resize the window. I gave each div the class **requirement** and tried the following jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(adjustRequirement);
        $(window).resize(adjustRequirement);

        function adjustRequirement(){
            var maxHeight = -1;

            $('.requirement').each(function() {
                maxHeight = maxHeight > $(this).height() ? maxHeight : $(this).height();
            });

            $('.requirement').each(function() {
                $(this).height(maxHeight);
            });
        }
</script>
```

Now this works whenever I load the page (or refresh with F5), but it does not work when I resize the window. What am I doing wrong? Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5qg1c3f9/).

Comment: I tried your code, it's working

Comment: @IsraGab Where? The fiddle shows the problem as described in Chrome.

Comment: @israGab I am using firefox 43.0.3 Which browser are you using? Does the fiddle work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this happens because you have set a fixed height on the first run of the function, this way the height will always be the same for every `div`. Since divs have by default `overflow: visible` the text will be shown even though it goes outside the `div`.

Try this, i have added a line where it resets the div's height so that it adjusts to fit the content `$(this).css('height', 'auto');`:

```
  $(document).ready(adjustRequirment);
  $(window).resize(adjustRequirment);

  function adjustRequirment(){
      var maxHeight = -1;

      $('.requirement').each(function() {
          $(this).css('height', 'auto');
          maxHeight = maxHeight > $(this).height() ? maxHeight : $(this).height();
      });

      $('.requirement').each(function() {
          $(this).height(maxHeight);
      });
  }
```

Comment: Good catch. Debugging shows that the function runs on resize. https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/jnf0ke98/8

Comment: @isherwood thanks. I had this same issue some time ago and stared at my code for a long time before realizing what was happening

Comment: @Adam You are welcome. Just keep in mind that having a div with "height: auto" might not always be the desired behavior so you have to change things accordingly

Answer (score 1):

You also can use [jquery-match-height](https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height). Just download and implement [jquery.matchHeight.js](https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height/blob/master/jquery.matchHeight.js)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    $('.requirement').matchHeight();
  }
});
```

it very easy to use and it works also on rezise.

Comment: YAP (Yet Another Plugin). Possibly a good resource, but probably overkill here.